# Text wrap issue in dropdown Select >option in Firefox browser

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to Wrap the text in the list of options within a dropdown.

I am trying to below css to formatting text in select option but not able to get solution in **firefox**.

```css
#selList option {
  padding: 0.5em;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  border-bottom: darkgray solid 1px;
}

#selList option:hover {
  padding: 0.5em;
  background-color: #3c8dbc;
  color: #fff;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<select multiple="" class="form-control Questions" id="selList" style="height: 350px; overflow: auto;">
<option value="54" catid="14" title="Click To Add" class="divScroll">Agrees to participate</option><option value="55" catid="14" title="Click To Add" class="divScroll">Medications</option>
<option value="56" catid="14" title="Click To Add" class="divScroll">Current Complaints - Patient reports that currently they</option><option value="57" catid="14" title="Click To Add" class="divScroll">Next Apt. confirmed - </option>
<option value="58" catid="14" title="Click To Add" class="divScroll">Provided Hotline No. - Patient is informed that they will be receiving a call the following month and that they will receive a statement in the mail. </option>
<option value="391" catid="14" title="Click To Add" class="divScroll">Hello Test question Hello Test question Hello Test question Hello Test question Hello Test question Hello Test question Hello Test question Hello Test question Hello Test question Hello Test question Hello Test question Hello Test question Hello Test question Hello Test question Hello Test question Hello Test question Hello Test question Hello Test question Hello Test question Hello Test question Hello Test question Hello Test question Hello Test question Hello Test question Hello Test question Hello Test question Hello Test question Hello Test question Hello Test question Hello Test question Hello Test question Hello Test question Hello Test question Hello Test question Hello Test question Hello Test question Hello Test question Hello Test question Hello Test question Hello Test question</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Styling `option` elements using CSS is notoriously unreliable. If you need any form of control over the UI of a `select`/`option` element you would be better off using a third-party library, such as Select2, to convert the elements in to a HTML structure which you have full control over.

Comment: You shouldn't be having this much content in select anyway. Show additional info on selected item beside select element on change. Also see supported attributes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select